# SharePoint WebService: Get List Item Navigation URL

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, url

I'm using the sharepoint's web service (GetListItems) method to get some fields data for list's items, now in addition for the information that i retrieve for an item **I need its direct URL**, so i can give the user an optional link to click in order to navigate smoothly to that item in the sharepoint website

here is my code that get's the item's data

```
 XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
                XmlNode ndViewFields =
                    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
                XmlNode ndQueryOptions =
                    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

                var cc = new CredentialCache();
                cc.Add(
                      new Uri(url),
                      "NTLM",
                      new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
                SPListWebService.Credentials = cc;
                SPListWebService.Url = url + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";


                //Query Options Node
                ndQueryOptions.InnerXml =
                    "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
                    "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
                //Qyery node
                foreach (DataRow row in view.Rows)
                {
                    string v = row[ffdmn].ToString();
                    ndQuery.InnerXml = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}'/>" +
                   "<Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>", sfdmname, v);

                    XmlNode ndListItems =
                        SPListWebService.GetListItems(listName, null, ndQuery,
                        ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);

                    foreach (XmlNode node in ndListItems.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                            foreach (XmlNode innerNode in node.ChildNodes)
                                if (innerNode.Name == "z:row")
                                {
                                   //I do some logic here to get the targeted fields
                                }
                    }
                }
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does ows_EncodedAbsUrl work?

innerNode.Attributes["ows_EncodedAbsUrl"].Value

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx

**EDIT**

Okay that works for document libraries, but for lists I think you are going to have to build the url.

First you need to load the list to get its url. (only do this once outside the for loop)

```
XmlNode ndList = SPListWebService.GetList("Driving License");
```

Then build the url per row.

```
string clickurl = url + ndList.Attributes["RootFolder"].Value + "/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + innerNode.Attributes["ows_ID"].Value
```

Check that there are enough '/'s

Comment: No it did not, *development-2:1112/sites/HRD/Lists/Driving%20License/1_.000 * is not a valid URL :S it should be *development-2:1112/sites/HRD/Lists/Driving%20License/DispForm.aspx?ID=1* instead

Comment: I also believe you need to build the URL yourselves. I have only work on client object model before and I end up building the URL myself too. The client object model is base on the web services so I don't think there is such data returned by the web services, but I am just a SharePoint newbie...

Comment: there is nothing called 'RootFolder' in node's attributes!

Comment: Can you attach here the value of ndList.OuterXml you are seeing. I expect something like: <List DocTemplateUrl=\"\" DefaultViewUrl=\"/Lists/XYZ/AllItems.aspx\" MobileDefaultViewUrl=\"\" ID=\"{91273D30-3CFA-49BF-8849-3029B8A41D9B}\" Title=\"XYZ\"

Comment: no need, im storing the raw url in database, just pulling the ID from the XML, thank you